# All shorten url redirecting to linkbucks

Tags: social-networking

I have seen most of shorten url like `http://owl.li/w6tUx` redirecting to linkbucks site. I see even google is using this service in their posts in facebook or google plus something like `http://goo.gl/Z7bY5C`. I am not sure why google like company is using services like linkbucks. Is this some kind of virus of something have affected my computer. Can someone please explain or please advise me what is the correct place to ask question like this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 2):

`owl.li`, `goo.gl` or any other sites are only url-shorteners. Most of them do not attach linkbucks or any other affiliate site by default, it up to the user using the service.

I believe in your case it was that whoever used `owl.li` pointed the URL to a linkbucks URL while Linkbucks URL was another kind of URL shortener which displays the real URL among Linkbucks ads.

---

**To explain the steps taken:**
- You have a website, say `http://www.example-domain.com/some-specific-long-url-you-want-short` *(as you can see, this is too long for one line, pity)*
- You go to a url-shortener (like `owl.li`) and insert the url.
- The url-shortener gives a short url back: `owl.li/exmlp`
- Some user clicks `owl.li/exmlp` and gets redirected to `http://www.example-domain.com/some-specific-long-url-you-want-short`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your router's been hacked into and its DNS server settings have been changed.
My advice: Reset Your Router/login to your router and remove the rogue DNS server entry, change the admin password for your router.